# bootstrap treeView not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I am using Admin LTE-Master. I want to make a dynamic left panel for showing the treeView menu items but it works only for the first list and not for the nested lists.
For better understanding of problem you can refer image [image] attached.
Following is the code that i have used:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib  prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Mines &#38; Geology | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Popper.js -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/popper.min.js"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/morris.js/morris.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">

  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck for checkboxes and radio inputs -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/iCheck/all.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Color Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap time Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
  <!-- Select2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css">

  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>

<body>
<aside class="main-sidebar">
 <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="resources/dist/img/guneet_profile.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>Guneet Kaur</p>
          <a href="/MinesAndGeology/home"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
      <form  id="menuform" class="sidebar-form"></form>

       <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">Navigation</li>
        <c:forEach items="${screenMappingData}" var="idM" varStatus="loop">        
           <li class="treeview">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>${idM.moduleName}</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu"> 
                    <c:forEach items="${idM.subModuleList}" var="idS" varStatus="loop2">
                        <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>${idS.subModule}
                            <span class="pull-right-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <c:forEach items="${idS.screenList}" var="idSc" varStatus="loop3">
                                    <li><a href="javascript:pagecall('${idSc.screenUrl}')">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>${idSc.screenName}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </c:forEach>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
      </ul> 
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="resources/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<!-- InputMask -->
<script src="resources/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap color picker -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap time picker -->
<script src="resources/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck 1.0.1 -->
<script src="resources/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="resources/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="resources/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="resources/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pagecall(screenUrl){

           document.getElementById('menuform').action=screenUrl;
           document.getElementById('menuform').submit();


    }
    </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

**Note: The content is coming from the list as i have seen it in the console but its not visible on the screen.**

**To be noted : Boostrap version is 3 not 4!**

I went through many similar questions but none of them helped me in resolving this issue. Please help!

Comment: Why is this tagged with `bootstrap-4` if you are using Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @WebDevBooster : there was no suggestion available for bootstrap-3 nor bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, there is. It's `twitter-bootstrap`. The old name. (I'd also rather have those tags updated to the current name)

Comment: @WebDevBooster : Thanks for sharing the knowledge!